# Filter dependency ressource files inside a child maven pom.xml

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-resources-plugin

I have a parent `pom.xml` which loads an assembly xml file (`build.xml`) from a `build-tools` module :

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.7-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>build</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptionRef>build</descriptionRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This `build.xml` file uses maven property delimiters like : `${output.build.directory}`

In the child project that uses the parent pom, I would like to replace delimited variables of the `ng-build.xml` file.

How can I do this ?

It seems that maven does not run delimiters replacement if they come from an external dependency.